# Class for controlling properties of the PictureBox (C# forms)

Tags: c#, forms, class

I am trying to write something along of a "clean" code... I want to make a Pong game, for now based on Forms.
I want to divide the game nicely into classes.

I want to have a ball class, AI that inherits from player class, I want to use the premade Form class for setting main Form properties (width etc).

I made a player class as such and I would like to ask you if the approach for naming, getters and setters and the general idea is correct. Isn't certain bits (if not all of it) rather redundant or badly written, I do not want to base entire "project" on bad assumptions and multiply the same mistakes all over the code.

```
namespace Pong
{
   public class Player
    {
        protected PictureBox PaddleBox { get; set; }
        protected Size PlayerSize
        {
            get
            {
                return PlayerSize;
            }
            set
            {
                if (PlayerSize.Height > 0 && PlayerSize.Width > 0)
                {

                    PlayerSize = new Size(value.Width, value.Height);
                    PaddleBox.Size = PlayerSize;
                }

            }


        }
        protected Point Location
        {
            get
            {
            return Location;
        }
        set
        {
          PaddleBox.Location = new Point(value.X, value.Y);
        }


    }
    protected Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            PaddleBox.BackColor = value;

        }
    }
    public Player()
    {

        PaddleBox = new PictureBox();

    }
}
```

}

FORM class looks something along of this for now, maybe I should pass parameters such as size,location and color in the constructor? What is the best?

```
namespace Pong
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Timer gameTime;
        const int screenWidth = 1248;
        const int screenHeight = 720;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.Height= screenHeight;
            this.Width=screenWidth;
            this.StartPosition=FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Player player = new Player();
            player.PaddleBox.Size = new Size(20, 50);
            player.PaddleBox.Location = new Point(player.PaddleBox.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height/2-player.PaddleBox.Height/2);
            player.PaddleBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            this.Controls.Add(player.PaddleBox);
        gameTime = new Timer();
        gameTime.Enabled = true;



    }

    void gameTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your player class exposes a property `PlayerSize` but you by-pass it and set the size of the picturebox directly `player.PaddleBox.Size = new Size(20, 50);`

Comment: PictureBox is a GUI element. I am not sure I would put it inside the classes. They should in general not be connected to the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You got an issue here:

```
protected Point Location
{
    get
    {
        return Location;   // <--- this is a circular reference..
                           //      meaning, it will recall this getter again.

    }
    set
    {
        PaddleBox.Location = new Point(value.X, value.Y);
    }
}
```

---

use this instead:

```
protected Point Location
{
    get
    {
        return PaddleBox.Location;
    }
    set
    {
        PaddleBox.Location = value;
    }
}
```

---

Same with `protected Color BackColor`

---

Here is an example, how I would implement it *(in your current programming style (powered by notepad))*

```
namespace Pong
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Timer gameTime;
        const int screenWidth = 1248;
        const int screenHeight = 720;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.Height= screenHeight;
            this.Width=screenWidth;
            this.StartPosition=FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            Player player = new Player(this);
            player.PlayerSize = new Size(20, 50);
            player.Location = new Point(player.PaddleBox.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height/2-player.PaddleBox.Height/2); // <-- the location is always the upperleft point. don't do this...
            player.BackColor = Color.Blue;

            gameTime = new Timer();
            gameTime.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void gameTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        private PictureBox _paddleBox;

        protected Size PlayerSize
        {
            get
            {
                return _paddleBox.Size;
            }
            set
            {
                if (PlayerSize.Height == 0 || PlayerSize.Width == 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Size must be greater than 0");

                _paddleBox.Size = value;
            }
        }

        protected Point Location
        {
            get { return PaddleBox.Location; }
            set { PaddleBox.Location = value; }
        }

        protected Color BackColor
        {
            get { return PaddleBox.BackColor; }
            set { PaddleBox.BackColor = value; }
        }

        public Player(Form form)
        {
            PaddleBox = new PictureBox();
            form.Controls.Add(PaddleBox);
        }
    }   
}
```

You should try to isolate the picturebox in your player class, this will separate the functionality of the form and the picturebox...

Comment: Do you reckon that setting everything line by line regarding player in form class as it is, is a better solution than setting it up via player constructor?

Comment: When a property is allowed to be changed after the constructor is called and the default value shoudn't be a problem, you shouldn't have to pass it to the constructor. In this case, new Point() isn't a problem.

Comment: You have deleted protected PictureBox PaddleBox { get; set; }, yet you call it in the construtor, you added _paddleBox instead. How should I understand, which part is an error?